# Android - How to have an grid with 3 images (height 33%, width 100%)

Tags: android, height, width, imagebutton

I'm a beginner in android development, so sorry if my question is east to solve. I tried to search on internet but nothing easy to use.

I tried to create an view like this one :

[image]

Can I succed to do that with a RelativeLayout or at least with a GridView ? 
Best regards,
Zed13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use Linearlayout with weightsum 3 and put three views with weight 1 in height this make your desired view.Like below instead of button use what ever you want view,layout etc they are perfectly divided.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f7f0db" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#17f0db" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#89f1db" />

</LinearLayout>
```